# Swift: Array Struct Image not visible in TableView

Tags: json, swift, uiimage, tableview, urlsession

me again with a new Question.
I´m gathering Picture Data from some JSON and fill it in an Array with a Struct as Datatype.
Everything works fine but when I try to display it in a TableView the Image is Missing - rest of Data is Displaying as wanted. 
But the Images seems to store in the Array too (See print after guard ---new pic added---).
Also Dispatch Group is completing with "All Done". 
Would be great if you could take a look and tell me what I´m doing wrong.

Array:

```
var memeRawData: [MemeRawData] = []
```

Struct:

```
struct MemeRawData {
    let name: String?
    let url: String?
    let img: UIImage?
}
```

Dispatch Group to gather Data from JSON and Download Image and append it to array:

```
        var meme = MemeRawData(name: "", url: "", img: UIImage())
        var memeName = ""
        var memeURL = ""
        var memeIMG = UIImage()

        let g = DispatchGroup()
            MemeAPI.requestAPIImageData { (imgData, error) in
                imgData?.data.memes.forEach{
                    memeData in
                    g.enter()
                    memeName = memeData.name!
                    memeURL = memeData.url!
                    MemeAPI.requestAPIImageFile(url: URL(string: memeData.url!)!) { (image, error) in
                        guard let image = image else {
                            print("PIC IS NIL")
                            return
                        }
                        memeIMG = image
                        print("-----NEW PIC ADDED-------")
                    }

                    meme = MemeRawData(name: memeName, url: memeURL, img: memeIMG)

                    self.memeRawData.append(meme)

                    g.leave()
                    }
                g.notify(queue:.main) {
                print("All done")
                }
        }
```

Function to get the Image from URL:

```
class func requestAPIImageFile(url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (UIImage?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else {
            completionHandler(nil, error)
            return}
        let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data)
        completionHandler(downloadedImage, nil)
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

And to complete it tableView dequeue:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "memeAPICell")

    cell?.textLabel?.text = memeRawData[indexPath.row].name
    cell?.imageView?.image = memeRawData[indexPath.row].img

    return cell!
}
```

Like I said JSON Parsing is working fine since I can display all URL´s and Names - but there seems to be a Problem with the Images. Also Console is not Printing out any Error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it just a timing issue?  if the image is downloaded after the tableview has been displayed then you will need to refresh each row of the tableview when the data arrives

Comment: I agree with @Russell. By the time you try to create the "MemeRawData" Object, the image is not downloaded.

Comment: @Russell 
Thanks for your Input! That would make sense too.. 
Is there a way to "hold" until the Image is Downloaded and can be stored in the Object? 
I´m pretty new to swift

Comment: the best approach is to display what you have, and update later - we don't ever want to hold up anything.  in 'cellForRowAt', we should check if the image is available - if it is, display it, if not, display a 'image coming soon... picture', and then refresh the specific row when the data comes.  If no-one beats me to it, I will share an example shortly

Comment: @Russell that would be great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the image in main thread,

write this function,

```
 func setImage(imageView:UIImageView,url:URL){
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){ (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil{
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let img = UIImage(data: data!)
                imageView.image = img
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

then call it in **cellForItemAt**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "memeAPICell")

    cell?.textLabel?.text = memeRawData[indexPath.row].name
    self.setImage(imageView:cell!.imageView!, url: URL(string: memeRawData[indexPath.row].url)!)

    return cell!
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks this is displaying the Image Correct but I was hoping that I can Pre-Load the Images in the Array since now when I Navigate to the TableView the Download begins and there is a little on wait time until all Images are Displaying. Thats why i tried to Store them in an Array and only pass them when navigating to TableView
Is there a Solution too?

Answer (score 0):

Set up your data array as you are already, and then for each element, download the image.  it won't be available the first time you show the tableview, but that's ok.  You have options for how you show that something is coming, here's a simple way to do it.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // set up your meme data as you do already

    // go get images in the background
    for index in 0...memeRawData.count-1 {
        print("Go get data for \(index)")
        getImage(index: index, url: URL(string: memeRawData[index].url ?? "")!)
    }
}

func getImage(index: Int, url:URL){
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){ (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil{
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("ready to reload /(index)")
            // now that you have the image, add it to your data array
            self.memeRawData[index].img = UIImage(data: data!)
            // now reload the specific row in your tableview
            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

then all you have to do is modify the way you display the tableview cell.  In this example, if there's no image available, I have changed the text display, but you could replace the image with a picture to show waiting, and if you have that included in your assets, you can have it available to display.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "memeAPICell")

    if memeRawData[indexPath.row].img == nil
    {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = memeRawData[indexPath.row].name! + " awaiting image ..."
    }
    else
    {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = memeRawData[indexPath.row].name ?? "title"
    }
    cell?.imageView?.image = memeRawData[indexPath.row].img

    return cell!
}
```